# How to remove specific lines from a text file?

Tags: python

I have two .txt files. One contains a list of domains (google.com, facebook.com, apple.com, amazon.com), each on a separate line. The other one contains a smaller list of domains (facebook.com, amazon.com), which are also each on a separate line.

I want to remove all the domains which are on the second text file, from the first text file.

So for example, the first text file would go from

```
google.com
facebook.com
apple.com
amazon.com
```

To:

```
google.com
apple.com
```

How could this be done with a python script?

Comment: You are aware of file handling?

Comment: SO is not here to write code for you - it is to debug problems with your existing code. Plese edit your question to show what you have already tried and what problems or errors you have encountered.

Comment: You want to make the difference between txt file2 from txt file1 right?

Comment: @EL-AJIOussama Yes.

Comment: @Shub Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this one.

```
f = open("text1.txt")
list1 = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
f.close()
f = open("text2.txt")
list2 = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
f.close()
def Diff(list1, list2):
    return list(set(list1) - set(list2)) + list(set(list2) - set(list1))
list1 = Diff(list1, list2)
f = open("text1.txt","w")
for i in list1:
    f.write(f"{i}\n")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer and stub:

```
with open('filename1.txt', 'r') as f:
  text1 = f.read()
with open('filename2.txt', 'r') as f:
  text2 = f.read()
with open('filename1.txt', 'w') as f:
  domains = text1.splitlines()
  keep_domains = text2.splitlines()
  new_domains = [d for d in domains if d in keep_domains]
  text = '\n'.join(new_domains)
  f.write(text)
```

This solution could work fine.

*Note:* I dislike method .readlines() of file object, I prefer string method .splitlines because first one keeps new line characters.
I dislike to use 'r+' mode when reading/writing file, I prefer to make it separately.

Answer (score 0):

**Python Diff**
To get a diff using the difflib library, you can simply call the united_diff function on it. For example, Lets say you have 2 files, file1 and file2 with the following content: Now to take their diff use the following code: This will give the output:

```
def Diff(li1, li2):
    return list(set(li1) - set(li2)) + list(set(li2) - set(li1))

li1 = ['google.com','facebook.com','apple.com','amazon.com']
li2 = ['facebook.com','amazon.com']

print(Diff(li1, li2))
```

**Compare Two Text Files**

```
file1 = "path to file"
file2 = "path to file"

import difflib
with open('file1') as f1:
    f1_text = f1.read()
with open('file2') as f2:
    f2_text = f2.read()
# Find and print the diff:
for line in difflib.unified_diff(f1_text, f2_text, fromfile='file1', tofile='file2', lineterm=''):
    print line
```

[image]